# Callback based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm learning Jquery and have a site calling hotel information.

I'm using ajax as the callback but I would like to know if anyone could show me some code or tutorials on how to make a callback dynamic as in it is based on the users input.

The user inputs dynamic data such as arrival and departure dates that builds the callback string needed for retrieval

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if "callback" is the word you're looking for, but you can pass data along with your AJAX call in the `data` property (which accepts a key/val pair). Consider:

```
<input type="text" id="arrival" />
<input type="text" id="depart" />

$.ajax({
    url: someUrl,
    data: {arrival: $("#arrival").val(), departure: $("depart").val() }
    ..
    ..
});
```